# How do you clear the contents (elements &|| text) of an element with BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Having got an element, how do you empty it with BeautifulSoup?

For example, I have a div (as shown below), what do I need to do to clear it's contents?

```
mydiv = soup.find("div", { "id" : "TopMostInfoBlockContent" })
mydiv.?? #Something here to clear the div contents?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`.clear()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#clear):

```
mydiv.clear()
```